# CSS Select element with 4 classes while 3 of them has the same start

Tags: css

I have an element, that has class `MuiTable-root jss51 jss52 jss53`.

Another element has class `MuiTable-root jss51`.

Numbers after `jss` can be different, but the number after the first `jss` in the first element and the only `jss` in the second element are the same. (eg. `MuiTable-root jss23 jss24 jss25` for the first element and `MuiTable-root jss23` for the second)

How do I select just the first element using css?

Edit:

Html I work with:

```
<div>
   <table class="MuiTable-root jss51 jss52 jss53">
      <colgroup>...</colgroup>
      <thead class="MuiTableHead-root">...</thead>
   </table>
   <table class="MuiTable-root jss51">
      <colgroup>...</colgroup>
      <tbody class="MuiTableBody-root">...</thead>
   </table>
</div>
```

I only need to change the instance of first table. I cannnot access `<div>` above the tables. I need to work purely using tables' classes. Again, number after `jss` are not always 51, 52, 53

Comment: `.MuiTable-root.jss51.jss52.jss53`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen well, numbers after jss could be another numers. It could be ```MuiTable-root jss21 jss22 jss23``` and ```MuiTable-root jss21```. I'll edit the question for clarification

Comment: Could you also add some code to show examples of the html you’re working with?

Comment: `table:first-child` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif wouldn't it affect the second table. Also I need to change the css properties of table itself and not its children

Comment: try it ........

Comment: @TemaniAfif wow, it does work. Thank you very much. It does not answer my original question but at least helps me with my task. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

use this selector:

```
.MuiTable-root:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

An explanation of this selector, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

Browser support - [check here](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Anth-of-type)

Answer (score 0):

If it is given that:

- at least one `jss` in the first `<table>` comes right after a class name that ends with a number between 0 and 9 (e.g. `jss51 jss52`)
- the `jss` in the second `<table>` does **not** come right after a class name that ends with a number between 0 and 9

You can check for a `jss` occurence, that comes right after a number `Y` between 0 and 9 with

```
[class*="Y jss"]
```

see [w3 documentation for reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-substrings):

> [att*=val]
> Represents an element with the att attribute whose value contains at least one instance of the substring "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

For example:

```css
[class*="0 jss"],
[class*="1 jss"],
[class*="2 jss"],
[class*="3 jss"],
[class*="4 jss"],
[class*="5 jss"],
[class*="6 jss"],
[class*="7 jss"],
[class*="8 jss"],
[class*="9 jss"]
{
color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="MuiTable-root jss51 jss52 jss53">
  <colgroup></colgroup>
  <thead class="MuiTableHead-root">
    <td>should be red</td>
  </thead>
</table>
  <table class="MuiTable-root jss51">
  <colgroup></colgroup>
  <tbody class="MuiTableBody-root">
    <td>should not be red</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```